# How to Right-click in Microsoft Remote Desktop?

Tags: applications, remote-control, mouse

I use Microsoft Remote Desktop to connect to my server from my Android Tablet (and mouse via OTG cable), but when I right mouse click closes RDP and exit. How is it possible to change it to call context menu (like on windows) when I right mouse click. (by the way it works on my android smartphone, but not on the tablet)
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From the [Microsoft RD for android FAQ](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn473010.aspx), following are the mouse gestures available on the Microsoft RD client for android,

[image: Screenshot]

`Direct touch` : 1 finger tap and hold

`Mouse pointer` : 2 finger tap

Read MS RD Client [FAQ page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473007.aspx) for more information.

If the above solution dint work for you, the other way to invoke a right click is to use the Windows On-screen Keyboard and press the context menu key which is in between the right-hand side <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> keys. Or Microsoft RD Client for Android provides a Keybord which you can open by clicking the keyboard icon at the top and press the <kbd>123</kbd> button to open an extended keyboard(shown in the screenshot below). Now Press the Right-Click mouse icon to perform the Right-click action on any particular object by selecting it.

[image: Screenshot_MSRD]
<sub>ScreenCapture - Clicking the right-click icon on the keyboard open the context menu on Windows RD client.</sub>

Comment: hm, but it doesn't work in that way, when I 2 finger tap, it works as double left mouse click. But when right mouse it says: Please press back once more to disconnect"...( I need call right mouse button)

Comment: You can have a workaround open the Windows keyboard and click the three vertical line button near alt and ctrl keys..@ihorko

Comment: I don't have keyboard, I have only mouse

Comment: @ihorko I m not talking about a Physical keyboard. I mean you can open the Windows Virtual Keyboard(start->type keyboard-> On-screen keyboard) and after opening the onscreen keyboard..click the button between the right side ALT and CTRL buttons..this would open the context menu for that particular screen.

Comment: Ah, I understand, thank you. I know about that way, but it's very unuseful therefore I posted this question. So on my phone right mouse click works as normal windows right mouse click and calls context menu, but on my tablet it wants to exit from RDP... hope it's clear now.

Comment: Yeah I get it. Will try it on myself the ms RD and update the answer if it work for me.

Comment: it works on my samrtphone, but doesn't on my MiPad tablet.... :(

Comment: @ihorko i couldn't test it on a tablet but the tap and hold works fine on Bluestacks. You need to hold down mouse for 3-5 secs which open the context menu after mouse button release. MS already has an inbuilt keyboard. Check my answer. You can use that anyway if nothing works. I'm not sure why there is different behaviour for tablet and mobile. Maybe your MiPad tablet has limited OTG support. //@webo80 did it work for you in a tablet or a mobile device?

Comment: Hm, yes i tried hold down left and right mouses for 3-5 seconds. So, on ANDROID: left button - opens context menu (like, copy, paste, it works exactly as keep down the finger for 3-5 sec). right button - back. On Windows RDP: left button - nothing happens (it's just like one left button click in windows). right button - back (and says: Please press back once more to disconnect)

Comment: If you tap on top of the screen where your remote user/domain/ip adress is visible it open a small window on the right with option to switch between mouse modes (ie. Direct touch and Mouse Pointer )..Make sure you have Mouse Pointer activated and try the two finger touch..Post a screenshot in you question adding more details..

Comment: YES, two finger works, it calls context menu. THANK YOU it helps much! Now only one question how to assign two fingers to right mouse button ??

Comment: @ihorko Ah Fine. Sorry I'm not sure I can find a way to assign mapping to the mouse like that. You can read more on the faq page. You can accept my solution if it solved your question.

Comment: "Lucky,

If you tap on top of the screen where your remote user/domain/ip adress is visible it open a small window on the right with option to switch between mouse modes (ie. Direct touch and Mouse Pointer )

What screen do you mean ?" - for @user3867146

Comment: @user3867146 I meant the "Remote Desktop screen" which you connect using the Microsoft RD Android client app. The Remote desktop client IP address will be visible at the top of the connection window.